Do parabolic inductions share a composition factor if and only if the inducing data are associate?
Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic zero and $G$ a connected reductive group over $F$. Let us call an inducing datum a triple $(P,M,\sigma)$, where $P$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$, $M$ is a Levi factor of $P$, and $\sigma$ is an irreducible admissible representation of $M(F)$. Let $I_{M,P}^G(\sigma)$ denote the normalised parabolic induction of $\sigma$.
Fix two inducing data $(P,M,\sigma)$ and $(P',M',\sigma')$. If $(M,\sigma)$ and $(M',\sigma')$ are $G(F)$-conjugate, it follows from the formula for the character of a parabolically induced representation that $I_{M,P}^G(\sigma)$ and $I_{M',P'}^G(\sigma')$ have the same character and therefore the same composition factors with multiplicity.
If $I_{M,P}^G(\sigma)$ and $I_{M',P'}^G(\sigma')$ share a composition factor, is it true that $(M,\sigma)$ and $(M',\sigma')$ are $G(F)$-conjugate?

This is true if $\sigma$ and $\sigma '$ are assumed to be supercuspidal (you do not need to assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero). The reference is Bernstein–Zelevinsky, Ann. Sci. ENS 1977.
Otherwise, you have obvious counter-examples as follows. Take $P=MU$ to be a proper parabolic subgroup, $\sigma$ an irreducible supercuspidal representation of $G$. Now take $P'=M'=G$ and $\pi '$ a composition factor of $I_{M,P}^G (\sigma )$.
